# How to handle push notification when app is in background but not suspended

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

My app receiving push notification, and showing appropriate info message for that. However when I'm clicking to the message, application becomes active but  application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not getting called which is right i think, since the application is not suspended and it just resigns active. The question is how i can make sure that user clicked to message when application becomes to foreground ?

Comment: First question is what do you mean  view button, I am not getting you btw if your app is in back ground mode and you will click on banner of notification then `didReceiveRemoteNotification` will be call

Comment: when the push notification comes and app is in background , the system prompts a view  in top of iphone with some message (from notification payload). However when i click to that view app becomes active but didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not called

Comment: `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` only call when your app is not activate.

Comment: i know, thats why i'm asking question here. Because in fact application is in background mode and user can open it from notification message by just tapping to message.

Comment: this question definitely needs more attention

Comment: I don't get why @taffarel isn't satisfied with `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

Comment: "The question is how i can make sure that user clicked to message when application becomes to foreground ?"

didReceiveRemoteNotification is ok, i need to read launchOptions when app becomes active to make sure that user clicks on notification message, when app is not suspended(but only in background) didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not getting called.

Comment: don't get your issue..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this app delegate method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application     
       didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

It will be called if your app is backgrounded, and the notification payload will be delivered in the userInfo dictionary. This contrasts with the situation when the app is launched from cold start, when this method does *not* get called, and instead you check in the launchOptions dictionary for the payload.

However the *preferred* way to do this since iOS7 is to use this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
       didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
             fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler;
```

This method is called when a user taps on a notification, regardless of whether the app is launched from cold start or foregrounded from background. So even if you are not using the completionHandler, it provides a more consistent way of accessing the notification payload. If this method is present, the older one does not get called.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are asking how to be sure that the app was brought into the foreground **as the result of the user “clicking” i.e. acting on a push notification**.

When the app is not running at all, you can use `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` as you mention. The launchOptions dictionary contains the payload, etc. — I won’t describe this since you already know how this works.

When the app IS running however, that method is not going to be called. Instead, `- application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is called. BTW this is called if the app was already in the foreground OR if it was in the background and the user “clicked” on the push notification banner/alert to open the app. It will not be called otherwise: so I believe this is *exactly* what you’re looking for.

The userInfo dictionary provided by this method will contain the notifications data, similarly to `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` for more ad-hoc processing. (Note: `userInfo` and `launchOptions` are semantically different, but hopefully this is obvious. :))